# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model during populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models

1.PageType Model

```
module.exports = (mongoose) => {
  const pageTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
      type: String,
    key: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
  });
  return mongoose.model('PageType', pageTypeSchema);
};
```

2. WorkFlow Model

```
    module.exports = (mongoose) => {
      const workFlowSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
          type: String,
          default: null,
        },
        key: {
          type: String,
          default: null,
        },
        level: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        page_type_id: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'PageType',
        },
      }, {
        timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
      });
      return mongoose.model('WorkFlow', workFlowSchema);
    };
```

But when I try to use **populate** it throws Schema hasn't been registered for model **PageType**

```
async getFlowById(flowId) {
 const result = await this.workFlow.findById(flowId).populate('page_type_id').exec();
 return result;
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this??

In app.js the models are included before routes also PageType model is also declared before WorkFlow model

Answer (score 0):

You typed wrong collection name. Collection name is Workflow and you are trying to findById at workflow. So i think Workflow should be there.  Just try with that.

Comment: Actually, in the constructor, **this.workFlow** is defined where it fetches the workFlow model